# Iterate over a List object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

How can I iterate over a List object in Javascript? It contain more than 1 value.

```
 List <controllerclass> obj = dao.listimpl();
```

I tried this:

```
 for (index = 0; index < obj .length; ++index) {
        console.log(obj [index]);
    }
```

Comment: yes,
and i'm also looking for that java script iteretor

Comment: please add details regarding how you're accessing the object from controller to front-end(javascript) For example: Model object or ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `List <controllerclass> obj = dao.listimpl();`this is java code you have pasted, try to paste the exact object which you trying to iterate.

Though i would recommend use a very lightweight javascript library Loadash which is very handy, when you are dealing with array/objects and looping through these items and many more util methods.

`_.forOwn(obj, function(value, key) { } );`

[Loadash - forOwn](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#forOwn)

Iterates over own enumerable string keyed properties of an object and invokes iteratee for each property. The iteratee is invoked with three arguments: (value, key, object). Iteratee functions may exit iteration early by explicitly returning false

Comment: can you explain with a example...?

Answer (score 1):

Looping using [Iterators in Javascript is new to ES6](http://es6-features.org/#GeneratorFunctionIteratorProtocol) and explained below.

[MDN Iterators and generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) - Explains that, in Javascript, an iterator is a data object that just has a next() method.  The result returned from Iterator.next() has a next() method, done and value properties.  An example is shown below using the Javascript Set object.

```
let aCollection = new Set(['item1', 'item2', 'item3']);
let it = aCollection[Symbol.iterator]();
console.log('iterator is', it)
console.log('it.done - is not meaningful', it.done); // notice that it.done is not defined!
let itLoop = it.next()
console.log('it.next()', itLoop);
console.log('it.next().value', itLoop.value);
console.log('it.next().done', itLoop.done);
```

Output of the above sample code is:

```
iterator is SetIterator { 'item1', 'item2', 'item3' }
it.done - is not meaningful undefined
it.next() { value: 'item1', done: false }
it.next().value item1
it.next().done false
```

[Set.prototype@@iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/@@iterator) - Explains how to use a Set iterator.  What puzzled me is why examples didn't include looping so I provide examples below.

### Using for...of

The easiest way to loop using an iterator is using the for(item of collection) syntax as described [here in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).  A more complete description of looping is [covered very well here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

```
for(let item of aCollection){
    console.log('for...of returns ', item);
}
```

### Using for(;;)

Next is a for loop using an iterator.

```
for(let it = aCollection[Symbol.iterator](), loop = it.next(); ! loop.done; loop = it.next()){
    console.log('for(;;) ', loop.value);
}
```

### Using while loop

And next is a while loop using an iterator:

```
let it = aCollection[Symbol.iterator]();
let loop = it.next();
while (! loop.done){
    console.log('while loop ', loop.value);
    loop = it.next();
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone.  The full runable example is at https://jsfiddle.net/PatS2265/y5a4hvb7/4/.  There is no HTML or CSS, just Javascript console.log output, so open a browser console window see the output.

Answer (score 0):

Object does not have length property like array.
Please use the following code to iterate

```
 for (var key in obj) {
          if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){

          alert("property  "+key+ " is " + obj[key] ); 
   }
  }
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: its returning objects only.....object has lot of values...i need to get the values from that object.........

Comment: my code will work with objects having enumerable property , this is JS code.